# Retrieving data from MongoDB causes "Cannot read property 'firstname' of null" error"

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have been trying to return some users info and to display them trough HTML. But I am getting the error:
"Cannot read property 'firstname' of null" error"
To store data I am using MongoDB, for the backend service Express and Node.js and for the frontend Angular.
To communicate between back and frontend I delegated that to HttpClient. Connection with Mongo works fine since my console receiving all data but when it comes to the frontend side it's giving me this issue.

routes-index.js  class  method for connection with MongoDB

```
router.get('/tasks', async (req, res) => {
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
res.json([
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db('angular-auth');
        dbo.collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            //db.close;
         });
      })
   ])
 });
```

tasks.service.ts class  method for returning data to frontend

```
getTasks() {
return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.URL + '/tasks');
}
```

private-tasks.component.ts class  ngOnInit() method which supposes to get and to subscribe data

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.tasksService.getTasks()
  .subscribe(
    res => {                             
      console.log(res);    //<===== this line is returning null value!
      this.tasks = res;                  
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
}
```

private-tasks.component.html class

```
<ul class="list-group">
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor='let task of tasks'>
  {{task.firstname}}
 </li>
</ul>
```

console.log(res); gives null value, but within if/else statement it's actually not null... How I am sure that is not... coz the same method is giving me output in the console. I have tried also to add ? to {{task?.firstname}} in that way I am not getting any error but still console.log(res); gives null value.

Is there anything that you can suggest how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the `res.json` call on the back-end side. The front-end side of the code seems good. The argument of the function call is supposed to be an object that you return from the server to the client, but what you'\re giving it instead if whatever MongoClient.connect returns -- which is probably nothing (I've never used it so I can't be sure).

The place where you call `console.log` is inside the innermost callback function. At the moment this piece of code runs, the database has responded and the response is ready to be sent to the client. But you attempt to send the data to the client *before* this callback is run.

So the correct approach is to place `res.json` inside the innermost callback, which runs when the data is available.

```js
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db('angular-auth');
  dbo.collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result); // <-- res.json goes inside, after data is available
  });
});
```

Comment: Lazar, you are God! "But you attempt to send the data to the client before this callback is run" I was doubting that this is the actual problem since the console.log(res) was giving me null, but in the terminal, I could see data! Finally, console.log(res) returns all the users. Still, nothing on display but I will find a way to solve it out

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an Async issue, here is what you can try in your service.ts file:

1. You will need to have some sort of mongo model to hold the data. For example:

```
 private tasks:TaskModel[] = []
```

2. In addition to a model, you will want to have a subject which you will need to import from rxjs.

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
```

and

```
private taskUpdated = new Subject<taskModel>[](); //create a new subject of type taskModel that you will add to
```

3. The last bit to update in your service.ts file would be this:

```
getTasks(){
   this.httpClient.get<any>(this.URL + '/tasks')
   .subscribe((taskData)=> {
       this.taskNotes = taskData;
       this.taskUpdated.next([...this.taskNotes])//adding in taskNotes
})

getTasksUpdatedAsListener(){
   return this.taskUpdated.asObservable();//observable that you will subscribe to in component.ts
}
```

4. Then in your component.ts file you will create another subscription object and change your code to this:

```
//subscription that needs to be created
private sub:Subscription;



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tasksService.getTasks()//this needs to go first. It will get data in the service file

    this.sub = this.taskService.getTasksUpdatedAsListener()
        .subscribe((data TaskModel[])=> {
           console.log(data);//you should see the data come in as json
        })


}
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Jexon thanks for your effort! I will try, but this doesn't look so helpful for me :) I have just started learning Node and Angular. And btw is this NEST.js or NODE.js? It looks like it's NEST.js

Comment: It's node, unless I somehow accidentally downloaded nest.js. Let me know if you are able to figure it out! I started learning angular a few months ago and was running into this issue until I found the solution I showed you. Everything I read said it was an async error so it may be worth your time to learn more about that as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and deleted the sessions in mongodb, the problem was solved.